# Typescript generic constraint not working when it is a variable property

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics, mapped-types

I am trying to get typescript generic to work when it is being used to access an object's property dynamically (inside square brackets).

**Minimal Example : **

```
export type TaskType = 'withdraw' | 'pickup'

interface Task<T extends TaskType = TaskType> {
  val: number
}

interface Memory {
  tasks : {
    [T in TaskType] : {
      [targetId: string]: Task<T>
    }
  }
}

const data: Memory = {
  tasks : {
    withdraw : {
      'a' : {val:  0}
    },
    pickup : {
      'a' : {val: 0}
    }
  }
}

const res1 =  data.tasks.withdraw.a; // Type is set correctly to Task<"withdraw">


let fn = function<T extends TaskType>(taskType: T) {
  const res2 = data.tasks[taskType].a; 
  // ^ Type here is not being infered. It is Task<"withdraw"> | Task<"pickup">
};
```

[Link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

As you can see in the above example when called outside the function with a specific key `res1` returns the correct type.

But when using a variable `data.tasks[taskType].a;` it dosent work. Type of `res2` should be `Task<T>`, instead it is something else. What am I doing wrong ?

### UPDATE : More Info

I feel like I should expand a bit more on what my actual problem is. The actual `Task` interface does not overlap between different `TaskTypes`. Also I have a function like the one shown below.

```
interface Task<T extends TaskType = TaskType> {
  val: number
  resourceType: T extends 'withdraw' ? string : undefined
}
...
let claim = <T extends TaskType>(taskType: T, task: Task<T>) => {
  data.tasks[taskType].a = task;  // Why is task not assignable here ?
}
```

[Link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3&filetype=ts#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)

Since `Task<T>` between various string do no have the same properties, the line `data.tasks[taskType].a = task;` throws an error.

I am calling the claim function like so :

```
const pickupTask = {val: 0, resourceType: undefined} as Task<`pickup`>;
claim('pickup', pickupTask) // The function will always be called with the same tasktype i.e. calling claim('withdraw', pickupTask) should throw an error
```

Logically speaking the parameter `pickupTask` should be able to be assigned to `data.tasks[taskType].a` since `taskType='pickup'`. So why is it throwing an error ? I might have misunderstood typescript generics, but I am not sure where I am wrong.

Also I cannot change Memory interface to be a generic interface.

Comment: I don't get the point. It's `Task<withdraw> | Task<pickup` because T is `withdraw|pickup`. It's not enforced to be a specific one.

Comment: @AndreiTătar But `T` should be what ever string is passed to the function. and hence `res` should be `Task<T>`. If not how do I achieve this ?

Comment: What type do you expect here `Type here is not being infered` ??

Comment: @captain-yossarian since `taskType` is of type `T` . I expect `res2` to be of the type `Task<T>`

Comment: @DollarAkshay `res2` is distributed over the union

Comment: @captain-yossarian Then, is there any way I can get `data.tasks[taskType].a` to be of type `Task<taskType>`  i.e. `Task<T>` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make small refactor of types and make `data` one of the arguments.

```js
export type TaskType = 'withdraw' | 'pickup'

interface Task<T extends TaskType = TaskType> {
  val: number
}

type Memory<Type extends TaskType> = {
  tasks: {
    [T in Type]: {
      [targetId: string]: Task<T>
    }
  }
}

const data: Memory<TaskType> = {
  tasks: {
    withdraw: {
      'a': { val: 0 }
    },
    pickup: {
      'a': { val: 0 }
    }
  }
}

const res1 = data.tasks.withdraw.a; // Type is set correctly to Task<"withdraw">


const fn = <
  Key extends TaskType,
  Data extends Memory<Key>
>(data: Data, taskType: Key) => {
  const res2 = data.tasks[taskType].a; // Task<Key>
};
```

`Memory` - should expect feneric `Type`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqBDAzgazc1AXjgHIB3ASxgAsATKDMkuAH1LAoGMcBXMEgFACKAOxjAoAMwydUmXAB40cUOJG0s6bHgJxi8nSgB8cAN4C4cAG4YANgC44IngFsARhIEBfIUhRwAWWAXaEQlXVVgdU0DfGM9MwsEbSxHc0tLAG1lUXQCAF00pIy4TJgMKABzYBgASVpHLBgoUUrCrUU0I2K4H0sfHwFOCBEmuFoMcscgkKgw2IITYnTk3FTEksoaekYikssSDBI06ztHAAZenq8AGh6Obj49-cPjs1OHOEu%20jJ%20BoWGo3gUGAWAAjAkJuUAHTlNbQrZ0BhkaEYADccAA9Ji8v4KJosDU4MMoCDODBbIgEBAOjgFAAiRE7Mj07oAkZjSQiBIKJIAaWAVMi0VpcWAd0sABFJhgVCA1BpAsFQgoBYhukYABRQjCOaXlG6rQzARxqgCUehMK0BYxBWAATJCZbCUmVtGL8qi0UlsXAAHq41DUCSofFOCDwDytOCiSQh2jQuC1eBhgwMpnI1msWkMh68MCs7xooA)

Comment: Hey man I have updated the question to include a bit more info about my actual problem. Sadly while I appreciate the effort chaning Memory to a generic type simple does not work for me.